# HasFlag always returns True

Tags: c#, enums

There is a way to check if I got a flag in a series of flag?

Example:

```
[Flags]
Enum TestEnum
{
  ALIVE, DEAD, ALMOSTDEAD, HURT, OTHERS

}
// check if is alive and has been hurt
TestEnum aTest = TestEnum.ALIVE | TestEnum.HURT
bool aTest2 = aTest.HasFlag(TestEnum.ALIVE)
```

But `a.Test.HasFlag` always returns true, even without the TestEnum.ALIVE

Comment: Yes there is. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Check the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx

Comment: i tried whit hasFlag, but it always return true, also without the TestEnum.ALIVE

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can certainly use [Enum.HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) like everyone has suggested. However, its important to make sure that your enumeration falls in powers of two. Powers of two have a single bit set, so your enumeration should look like this:

```
Enum TestEnum
{
    ALIVE = 1, DEAD = 2, ALMOSTDEAD = 4, HURT = 8, OTHERS = 16
}
```

The reason this is important is because you are comparing the bit flags. In memory, your enum flags will look like this:

```
ALIVE      = 00001
DEAD       = 00010
ALMOSTDEAD = 00100
HURT       = 01000
OTHERS     = 10000
```

When you do a bitwise compare, like `DEAD | ALMOSTDEAD`, you are doing this:

```
DEAD       = 00010
           OR
ALMOSTDEAD = 00100
------------------
RESULT     = 00110
```

Since the Result is > then 0, its true.

Comment: A easy way to do the powers of two when assinging them is to use the `<<` operator. `Enum TestEnum
{
    ALIVE = 1<<0, DEAD = 1<<1, ALMOSTDEAD = 1<<2, HURT = 1<<3, OTHERS = 1<<4
}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this as FLAGS I believe your declaration is wrong. Check out this previous post. Because of the default incrementing, HasFlag won't work as you expect unless you set the values to powers of 2.

[What does the [Flags] Enum Attribute mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c/8526#8526)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enum.HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) to check for this.

```
bool aTest2 = aTest.HasFlag(TestEnum.ALIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making a game, so you should make a class for this issue

```
public class Player
{
    bool isAlive;
    bool isHurt;
...
}
```

Later you could check your states like this:

```
if (player.isAlive && player.isHurt)
{
 //dosomething
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do bitwise operation like this:

```
var alive = TestEnum.Alive;
var hurt = TestEnum.Hurt;
var aliveAndHurt = alive & hurt;
```